# Prevent form autorefreshing

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a simple form. I am handling its submission. When submitting, There is a problem on my Android device. The page refresh and nothing happens. Second click does the trick and sends an AJAX call. Do you have any idea how to fix it? There are no syntax errors. It works without refreshing in my browser. It refreshes on Android.

Here is a code:

```
<form method="post" name="logowanie" data-ajax="false" id="form">

            <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>   
            <label for="haslo">Hasło:</label>
            <input type="password" name="haslo" id="haslo"/>

            <button id="submit" type="submit" data-theme="e">Zaloguj</button>

</form>
```

I am handling form this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

    Ajax call

    return false;
   }  
}
```

Comment: add a return false to your code

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:-

```
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

.....

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     alert('test');
    return false;
    });  
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some ")" missing.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

    //Ajax call
    alert('test');
    return false;
   });  
});

</script>
```

Comment: they are optional,arent they ?

Comment: I do not think so. However, for readability, you'll _always_ want to use semicolons.

Comment: Semicolons are optional and if you are leaving lines after every statement, there is no problem of readability. But if you want to minify your script in the future, you may want to use them.